# How do I correct returning a local or temporary in this template code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11, stdbind

I'm binding a copy_if into a function object that will accept a pair of iterators. I have a warning that I'm returning a local address or temporary.

I've come as far as knoing it comes from binding member variables of an std::pair of iterators, but I don't know how to correct it. I don't understand why they're considered temporary in the first place. Can someone explain both to me?

Here is the relevant code. The environment is Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, and less helpfully Windows 7 Enterprise.

```
std::vector<My_Type *> destination_container;

typedef /*A boost multi index iterator that dereferences to a 'My_Type *' */ t_range_iterator;
typedef std::pair<t_range_iterator, t_range_iterator> t_equal_range;
typedef std::function<bool(My_Type *)> t_predicate;
typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::vector<My_Type *>> t_inserter;

t_predicate predicate(std::bind(&My_Type::pred, std::placeholders::_1, SOME_CONST));

std::function<t_inserter(const t_equal_range)> do_copy_from(std::bind(&std::copy_if<t_range_iterator, t_inserter, t_predicate>
    , std::bind(&t_equal_range::first, std::placeholders::_1)
    , std::bind(&t_equal_range::second, std::placeholders::_1)
    , std::back_inserter(destination_container)
    , predicate));
```

And then later, the code will be doing something like this:

```
do_copy_from(return_me_an_equal_range_of_My_Type_ptr());
do_copy_from(get_me_another_equal_range());
do_copy_from(and_so_on_dot_dot_dot());
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use a struct with a template operator() function for this?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; it's pragmatic. There are several things I could do to fix this, but I don't consider them as graceful. Ultimately, I will probably use such a solution and move on with my life.

More importantly, though, this problem illustrates a lack of understanding I want to rectify, so I don't have to keep coming back here and asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not Enought code.  But at a guess it's because the destination_container container is local
and the back_inserter is keeping a reference to it.

Comment: I had commented earlier, disagreeing with you, but now I'm not so sure... But why would a reference to a local be a bad thing? It's not like the container is going to fall out of scope in the lifetime of the function object. Are you implying that the reference stored in the back inserter is falling out of scope?

Comment: if the function object was returned from the scope, yes.

Comment: but I don't *know* that's what's happening.
It also might be buried in the implementation of the boost multi index iterator...  which I *really* don't want to read.. I mean I love me some boost, but Template meta programming is a pain to read.